# a new symbol: can we make a symbol like this

Tags: symbols

[image: a new symbol]

Can we build a new symbol given above. It seems letter "t" but with two medium line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That symbol is the Turkish New Lira. Apparently it's been added to Unicode last year. Most fonts don't see it and indeed Arial Unicode MS displays a square.

But if you use this new font, [Rupakara](http://www.evertype.com/fonts/rupakara/), it supports the symbol. Note that it doesn't support accented letters as in `à, è, ü`. The alternative would be either to use a small image, or to try Unicode but this second option might not work. I was trying earlier and nothing worked.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Rupakara}

\begin{document}\Huge

₺ 

\end{document}
```

The symbol you see is not the same as the quotes `"`, so if you need to type it multiple times, you could set a `\newcommand` in your preamble as in

```
\newcommand{\CommandNameHere}{₺}
```

Comment: Ah. But you are a Italian citizen :-)...my best regards.